# Can't connect two devices via Googles Nearby API

Tags: java, android, google-nearby

I'm developing an app which can share local music on your phone to other devices. To connect several devices I am using Googles Nearby API. After starting to advertise and to discover on two devices, the onEndpointFound calls a found device on both devices. To accept this connection the app should show up an AlertDialog. This happens in the onConnectionInitiated method. But for some reason the app won't get to the part where the AlertDialog is built.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

This is the code:

```
package com.shuzo.musicshare;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.nearby.Nearby;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.AdvertisingOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.ConnectionInfo;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.ConnectionLifecycleCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.ConnectionResolution;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.ConnectionsClient;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.ConnectionsStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.DiscoveredEndpointInfo;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.DiscoveryOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.EndpointDiscoveryCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.Payload;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.PayloadCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.PayloadTransferUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.Strategy;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MusicShare";

    private static final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS =
            new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            };

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = 1;

    private static final Strategy STRATEGY = Strategy.P2P_STAR;

    EditText usernameEdit;
    Button connectButton;

    private ConnectionsClient connectionsClient;

    // Callbacks for receiving payloads
    private final PayloadCallback payloadCallback =
            new PayloadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPayloadReceived(String endpointId, Payload payload) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPayloadTransferUpdate(String endpointId, PayloadTransferUpdate update) {

                }
            };

    // Callbacks for connections to devices
    private final ConnectionLifecycleCallback connectionLifecycleCallback =
            new ConnectionLifecycleCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionInitiated(final String endpointId, ConnectionInfo connectionInfo) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionInitiated: accepting connection");
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    alertDialog
                            .setTitle(R.string.accept_connection_title + " " + connectionInfo.getEndpointName())
                            .setMessage(R.string.confirm_codes + " " + connectionInfo.getAuthenticationToken())
                            .setPositiveButton(
                                    R.string.accept_connection,
                                    (DialogInterface dialog, int which) ->
                                            connectionsClient.acceptConnection(endpointId, payloadCallback))
                            .setNegativeButton(
                                    android.R.string.cancel,
                                    (DialogInterface dialog, int which) ->
                                            connectionsClient.rejectConnection(endpointId))
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionResult(String endpointId, ConnectionResolution result) {
                    switch (result.getStatus().getStatusCode()) {
                        case ConnectionsStatusCodes.STATUS_OK:
                            Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionResult: status ok");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case ConnectionsStatusCodes.STATUS_CONNECTION_REJECTED:
                            Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionResult: connection rejected");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection rejected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case ConnectionsStatusCodes.STATUS_ERROR:
                            Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionResult: error");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        default:
                            // Unknown status code
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnected(String endpointId) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Device disconnected");
                }
            };

    private final EndpointDiscoveryCallback endpointDiscoveryCallback =
            new EndpointDiscoveryCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onEndpointFound(String endpointId, DiscoveredEndpointInfo info) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onEndpointFound: endpoint found, connecting");
                    connectionsClient
                            .requestConnection(getUserNickname(), endpointId, connectionLifecycleCallback)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(
                                    (Void unused) -> {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "onEndpointFound: successful");
                                    })
                            .addOnFailureListener(
                                    (Exception e) -> {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "onEndpointFound: failed");
                                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onEndpointLost(String endpointId) {

                }
            };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        connectionsClient = Nearby.getConnectionsClient(this);

        connectButton = findViewById(R.id.connectButton);

        connectButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            startAdvertising();
            startDiscovery();
            connectButton.setEnabled(false);
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (!hasPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS)) {
            requestPermissions(REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }

    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void startAdvertising() {
        AdvertisingOptions advertisingOptions =
                new AdvertisingOptions.Builder().setStrategy(STRATEGY).build();
        connectionsClient
                .startAdvertising(getUserNickname(), getPackageName(), connectionLifecycleCallback, advertisingOptions)
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        (Void unused) -> {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.advertising_success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        (Exception e) -> {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.advertising_fail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        });
    }

    private void startDiscovery() {
        DiscoveryOptions discoveryOptions =
                new DiscoveryOptions.Builder().setStrategy(STRATEGY).build();
        connectionsClient
                .startDiscovery(getPackageName(), endpointDiscoveryCallback, discoveryOptions)
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        (Void unused) -> {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.discovery_success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        (Exception e) -> {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.discovery_failed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        });
    }

    private String getUserNickname() {
        usernameEdit = findViewById(R.id.usernameEdit);
        return usernameEdit.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the additional detail in the comments, this appears to be a Bluetooth Classic issue. I looked in our records, and we have both reported devices so we'll try to reproduce on our end.

Some steps you can do:
1) Try rebooting the devices and see if the issue is reproducible.
2) Collect logs (adb logcat) or a bugreport (adb bugreport) from both devices and attach them to this post or email them to me directly at {my username}@google.com. These contain sensitive data, so only send it if you have test accounts on both devices. If you have a personal account, then filter the logs first (adb logcat NearbyConnections:* NearbyMediums:* *:S)

Disclaimer: I work on Nearby Connections

Comment: Well, it didn't fix my problem. The problem is that the app won't get to the point where the AlertDialog is built. The log doesn't show "onConnectionInitiated: accepting connection" like it should.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird then. The rest of the code looks right. Do you see your "onEndpointFound: success" or "onEndpointFound: failed" messages? If you get a FAILED result for requestConnection, you won't make it to onConnectionInitiated

Comment: Can you also attach logs for "Nearby connections" and "NearbyMediums"? That should let us know what's happening under the hood

Comment: First I get "onEndpointFound: endpoint found, connecting" and after a few seconds I get a Toast on my phone that I'm not able to pair to the other device and I should have a look that the other device is ready to pair. The log then gives me "onEndpointFound: failed". I also enabled nearby device connections in my system settings of both phones but it didn't work either.

Comment: adb logcat NearbyConnections:* NearbyMediums:* *:S

But from the sound of it, you're running into a problem with Bluetooth Classic. We use insecure rfcomm, which is supposed to create a BT connection w/ no user-visible confirmation, but some devices don't respect it. Can I have the Build.MANUFACTURER, Build.MODEL, and Android OS version of your phones?

Comment: Both phones are samsung. The first one is an SM-G950F running Android 9 and the second is an SM-A520F running Android 8.

Comment: We weren't able to reproduce on our two devices. Are you still seeing this issue after a reboot?

Comment: Still seeing the issue... I'll try to use another phone 'cause the A520F is a business phone... Maybe the locked something

Comment: After using a different phone (SM-A405FN running Android 10) first it says "Unable to start discovery but after a few seconds I get the AlertDialog for accepting the connection and the Toast says "Connected".

Comment: So I'm now trying to get my app to work on a Samsung Galaxy S6 edge running Android 7 and the same problem appears again like on the A5 2017. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I'm also unable to connect these two devices directly via Nearby on the Google settings.

Comment: Sent you the adb logcat via email!